# Magnet link sometimes does not open Transmission

Tags: 14.04, transmission, torrent-client

After doing a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04, Magnet links sometimes do not open Transmission, Its my only torrent client and i need to restart mt computer to get it working.

How can i fix this? Im using CHROME

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: In Firefox? - Goto Preferences > Applications and define what to do when clicking on a magnet-link.

Comment: im using CHROME

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug report about this on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1325237

Solution mentioned there: click on the "choose" button and go to /usr/bin and select transmission as startup application.